Unable to Boot Ubuntu After Upgrading to 24.04
I upgraded Ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04. I have a dual boot setup with Windows 11. Everything was working fine before the upgrade. The Grub menu still shows up perfectly fine, with the addition of two “Memory Test” options.
One thing I tried was disable secure boot through BIOS, but Ubuntu still persisted on not booting up. I don’t even get an indicator from Ubuntu.
Another thing I noticed is that I get the message “bad shim signature” when I click on either “Memory Test,” though this works after I disable secure boot. Not sure if that has something to do with Ubuntu not booting up.
Any advice on what I could look into to make Ubuntu boot?
